# Python script failing during Xcode Bot pre-integration trigger

Tags: python, xcode, continuous-integration

My pre-integration script runs like so:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
cd ${XCS_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjectName
./Script/prebuildscript.py
```

`prebuildscript.py` is a Python 2 script, that starts like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

success = subprocess.call([os.path.join(script_dir,'another_script.py')])
```

`another_script.py` is a Python 3 script, with the following hashbang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

In the bot's trigger log output, I'm seeing the following error:

> env: python3: No such file or directory

When I run the `/usr/bin/env python3` command from a Terminal prompt, as my account, and as **_xcsbuildd**, I get the usual `>>>` REPL prompt. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `set` line to your trigger's script, you'll see all of your environment variables. Chances are, your `PATH` is missing `/usr/local/bin`. Correct your trigger's script, like so:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:${PATH}
cd ${XCS_SOURCE_DIR}/ProjectName
./Script/prebuildscript.py
```